# como acessar o array de classes com jQuery? Pegar a segunda classe de um elemento

Tags: jquery, classes, arraylist, dom

Eu estou listando os ícones de uma lista no `console.log()` eles são exibidos, porem eu quero capturar somente as segundas classes do ícones em uma variável, porem não sei como acessar com jQuery as segundas classes da tag `<i>`.
Estou usando esse código para acessa as tag's `<i>` que estão na lista `<li>`

```
clickAtual = $('li.card').children().find('i');
```

Abaixo a lista é exibida, porém eu quero acessar a segunda classe desta lista exibida conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: exibição da lista no console.log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há necessidade de usar `.children()`. O `.find()` já irá encontrar tudo (filhos, netos, bisnetos, tataranetos etc.):

```
$('li.card').find("i")
```

A partir daí, usando o laço `.each()` você consegue fazer um *split* nas classes dos elementos e pegar o índice `[1]` (segunda classe) de cada uma e guardar numa array. Com a array montada você pode converter em string, iterar, fazer o que quiser:

```js
var clickAtual = $('li.card').find("i");
var array = [];
clickAtual.each(function(i,e){
   var c = e.className.split(" ")[1];
   array.push(c);
});


console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="card">
      <i class="classe1 classe2 classe3"></i>
      <i class="classe1 classe21 classe3"></i>
      <i class="classe1 classe22 classe3"></i>
      <i class="classe1 classe23 classe3"></i>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Mano, deu super certo aqui, '.find()' busca tudo mesmo, valeu obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma:

```
classeDesejada = $('li.card').children().find('i:eq(0)');
```

Você passa no `:eq()` a posição desejada. Veja mais sobre o [eq-selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) na documentação do `JQuery`.

Comment: Eu tentei aqui porém o console continua a imprimir todas as classes. Eu olhei o document '.eq()' do jQuary.